# How to write the contents of a Onedrive<Item> to a local file

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, onedrive

In my app, I am using OneDrive to keep data in sync. I am successfully writing the file to OneDrive, but am having no luck replacing the local outdated data with the newer OneDrive data.

My current method, which completes without throwing an exception, does not return the same text data that the file on OneDrive contains.
Goal of the method is to compare the datemodified to the OneDrive file to the local file, and if OneDrive is newer, write the contents of the OndeDrive file to the local StorageFile, and then return it to be de-serialized.

```
private async Task<string> GetSavedDataFileAsync(string filename)
    {
        string filepath = _appFolder + @"\" + KOWGame + @"\" + filename;
        StorageFile localread;
        BasicProperties localprops = null;
        string txt;
        try
        {
            localread = await local.GetFileAsync(filepath);
            localprops = await localread.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        { localread = null; }
        if (_userDrive != null)
        {
            if (_userDrive.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                try
                {
                    Item item = await _userDrive.Drive.Special.AppRoot.ItemWithPath(filepath).Request().GetAsync();
                    if (item != null)
                    {
                        DateTimeOffset drivemodified = (DateTimeOffset)item.FileSystemInfo.LastModifiedDateTime;
                        if (localprops != null)
                        {
                            if (drivemodified > localprops.DateModified)
                            {
                                Stream stream = await localread.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
                                using (stream)
                                { await _userDrive.Drive.Special.AppRoot.ItemWithPath(filepath).Request().GetAsync(); }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (OneDriveException e)
                {
                    if (e.IsMatch(OneDriveErrorCode.ActivityLimitReached.ToString()))
                    { string stop; }
                }
            }
        }
        if (localread == null) return string.Empty;
        txt = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(localread);
        return txt;
    }
```

I tried to reverse engineer another answer I found on Stack regarding writing a StorageFile to OneDrive, in that I needed to open the stream of the local file, but I doesn't appear to be working properly.

Comment: Did you manage to make it work? Because my local and remote files never have the same same DateTimeOffset. And if they are always different my app will be always downloading and uploading them all. I need this control for the same reason that you do. Control the sync. Thanks

Comment: @Dpedrinha In short, yes. The answer below allowed me to write the contents from a OneDrive item to a local file. When I do the local vs Ondrive comparison my code looks like `var localinfo = await localfile.DateModified;` then `var localtime = localinfo.DateModified;` then `var oneDtime = (DateTimeOffset)oneDItem.FileSystemInfo.LastModifiedDateTime;` and finally `switch (oneDtime > locattime)` Let me know if you need further info and I can send you the full method.

Comment: Yes please, that would be helpful. My local file (StorageFile) has no DateModified attribute. It has only DateCreated. And it's always different from the remote file.

Comment: I managed to get the DateModified with localFile.GetBasicPropertiesAsync(). But the DateCreated and Modified dates between the local and remote files are always different. Which makes my code keeps downloading and uploading files. Thanks

Comment: @Dpedrinha, sorry for taking so long - real life got the better of me. I've loaded the whole method I use to a text file on my OneDrive, link at the end of the comment. However, I'm not entirely sure this is stopping the download of the One Drive file, since I think that occurs during the GetAsync() method (though I am by no means an expert), so you have to download it to compare date modified. Here's the share link, good luck. https://1drv.ms/t/s!AnDnNExyKCYZ2-4UQS5URA1F9KNluA

Comment: Also, when the user changes data, I specifically write the changes to OneDrive first, then to local. This way, I know that the data on the same device will be newer than the OneDrive data, and on other devices, One Drive will be newer, so will replace that device's local store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the content of a OneDrive item, we need use following method:

```
var contentStream = await _userDrive.Drive.Special.AppRoot.ItemWithPath(filepath).Content.Request().GetAsync();
```

While using

```
await _userDrive.Drive.Special.AppRoot.ItemWithPath(filepath).Request().GetAsync();
```

you are getting the OneDrive `Item` not its content.

So you can change your code like following to write the content of a Onedrive item to a local file:

```
if (drivemodified > localprops.DateModified)
{
    using (var stream = await localread.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    {
        using (var contentStream = await _userDrive.Drive.Special.AppRoot.ItemWithPath(filepath).Content.Request().GetAsync())
        {
            contentStream.CopyTo(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's appears to be doing exactly what I need it to.